# Android data binding ternary operator error

Tags: android, data-binding, ternary-operator, android-databinding

I'm trying to bind the `enabled` value of an `ImageView` using data binding with an `ObservableInt` in a ternary operator like this:

```
<variable
            name="myInt"
            type="android.databinding.ObservableInt"/>
...
<ImageView
        ...
        android:enabled='@{myInt > 1 ? false : true}'
        ...
        />
```

It works exactly as expected.

But when I change the expression to

`android:enabled='@{myInt < 1 ? false : true}'`

It throws the following compilation error:

> The value of attribute "android:enabled" associated with an element type "ImageView" must not contain the '<' character.

Why can I check if `myInt` is larger than 1 but can't check if it's smaller than 1?

Comment: Maybe you need to escape the `<` character as the XML parser is reading it as starting a new element. Not exactly sure on the syntax for doing so, but that would be my guess.

Comment: @ThomasCook is exactly right. But why not just change the false and true like `android:enabled='@{myInt > 1}'` should do the trick

Comment: @Thomas you're absolutely right! It works like a charm.

Comment: I know, I know *blushes*

Comment: @Pierre you're also right but it probably won't be possible in every situation.

Comment: Then rethink your logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape characters for xml something like this:

```
android:enabled="@{myInt &lt; 1 ? false : true}"
```

Comment: You are rught, my bad

Comment: There is a bugreport on this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119876558